# Inserting into mysql database AES_ENCRYPT using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, pdo, aes

I am trying to encrypt the data values when inserting into MYSQL using AES_ENCRYPT and CBC encryption mode:

```
SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
```

If I insert the data directly in SQL, it successfully inserts without any problem.

However, if I insert through PHP using prepared statements (PDO), the data doesn't insert into the database and I receive no error and the lastInsertID returned is `0`.

If I remove the `AES_ENCRYPT` part, it inserts the data successfully.

Complete code:

```
$sql .= "SET @IV = RANDOM_BYTES(16);";
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO ". TABLE_NAME. " (record_created, name, dob, someinfo, iv) 
            VALUES (
                NOW(), 
                :name,
                AES_ENCRYPT(:dob, :key, @IV), 
                AES_ENCRYPT(:someinfo, :key, @IV),  
                @IV); ";



        try {
            $db = Employee::getConnection();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  

            $stmt->bindParam(':key', $key);
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $employee->name);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dob', $employee->dob);
            $stmt->bindParam(':someinfo', $employee->someinfo);

            $stmt->execute();
            $employee->id = $db->lastInsertId();
            $db = null;
            echo json_encode($employee);
```

Comment: `:name',`? is it a typo?

Comment: @u_mulder, no it isn't. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Why there's a `'` after `name`?

Comment: @u_mulder, my bad. I don't know how I missed it. I removed it, yet same problem. `lastInsertId()` is returning 0 and data is not being inserted.

Comment: So check errors. AFAIK `$stmt->errorInfo`

Comment: @u_mulder, throwing the error `Undefined property: PDOStatement::$errorInfo`

Comment: It's a function. my fault, but don't you have google?

Answer (score 3):

you can't fire multiple Querys seperateted with ";" like in PhpMyAdmin.
This is a way, you may prefer:

```
<?php
$aeskey = '4ldetn43t4aed0ho10smhd1l';

$sql = "INSERT INTO ". TABLE_NAME. " (record_created, name, dob, someinfo) 
            VALUES (
                NOW(), 
                :name',
                AES_ENCRYPT(:dob, '".$aeskey."'), 
                AES_ENCRYPT(:someinfo, '".$aeskey."'));";

$db = Employee::getConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $employee->name);
$stmt->bindParam(':dob', $employee->dob);
$stmt->bindParam(':someinfo', $employee->someinfo);
$stmt->execute();
$employee->id = $db->lastInsertId();
$db = null;
echo json_encode($employee);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've tried inserting this way and it works but I want to use CBC encryption mode which requires IV as a parameter. How would I enter that?

Comment: I'm doing the same thing, and it's possible that you must create another column in the table for the IV, and then generate a random IV for each item, and store it with the value.  I  assume this because I have not been able to use @iv with the PHP PDO yet.